# two columns of text per output line powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to make my output look something like this:

First line of text     Second line of text

Third line of text     Fourth line of text
...

I'm having the hardest time figuring out how to do this.

I have an array of strings, and they're pretty close to the same length. Sadly, they're many (in excess of 50), and to display them as a menu is rather ungainly.

I'd also be very happy just splitting it down a third, after a specified number, and displaying the rest in a second and third column.

1     26    51

.     .     .

.     .     .

25    50    *
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have no example to give, other than what I gave. I have no error codes, none are given (because there is no error, it's just not done).

Comment: Show part of what you wrote...

Comment: No. What I wrote works fine, I want to do it a different way. I just want it in columns. Why is this hard? I want to output into columns. I don't know how to do that, I am asking how to do that. It really doesn't matter what I have, as I will adapt it to how it's done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Format-Wide` can format your output the way you describe, unfortunately it doesn't accept a raw string array as input.

If you have an array of strings, you can use `Select-Object` to create pipeline objects you can feed to `Format-Wide`:

```
$linesOfText = @(
  "First line of text",
  "Second line of text",
  "Third line of text",
  "Fourth line of text"
)

$linesOfText |Select-Object @{Name='String';Expression={$_}}|Format-Wide String -Column 2
```

You should see the output in 2 columns, like:

> ```
> First line of text                             Second line of text
> Third line of text                             Fourth line of text
> ```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed.